# Using Run Anything for Flutter commands on Intellij

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, command, action

I want to use Flutter commands to Run Anything popup. I was doing this on VS Code, but couldn't do it on IntelliJ. I searched a lot but couldn't find the info I want.
Below pictures show what I want to do.

**This is how I use it on VSCode**

[image: This is how I use it on VSCode]

**This is IntelliJ, which has no commands for Flutter**

[image: This is IntelliJ, which has no commands for Flutter]

Also, I manually tried running commands like

> flutter pub get

**but it results with this**

[image: but it results with this].

Comment: commands have to be provided by Flutter plugin; I'd suggest submitting a request to https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Is it not possible for me to create my own custom commands?

Comment: no, you can't...